# Plotting x and y according to given equations

Tags: nonlinear-system

Hello i am trying to come up with two resistor values in my school project circuit and i wonder could these two equations give me a x,y plot:

$$x*y=20*(x+y) \tag{1} $$

$$x*(y+100)=60*(x+y+100)\tag{2}$$

$$1000>x,y>0 \tag{3}$$

I would be so glad if you could guide me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x*y%3D20*%28x%2By%29+AND++x*%28y%2B100%29%3D60*%28x%2By%2B100%29+from+100%3Cx%3C200%2C+0%3Cy%3C100) what you're wanting?

Comment: yes that will do it. thank you very much.

Comment: No problem. :-)